# Multiple items not displaying in my Cart [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, fetch

am building a small E-commerce site, where I want to display the cart details but when I try to add more than one item to the cart, only one item will displaying in cart page.

**How I coded for displaying items in Cart:**

1. I have a (Home Page) HomePage.jsx, where i will display the all the products through API. and i have a Button `VIEW DETAILS` for earch Items.
2. clicking on `VIEW DETAILS` button will navigate to Another jsx component i.e. ProductDetails.jsx, where i will display products details with `ADD TO CART` button, when we click on that button, it will send a props to `Header.jsx` component for displaying Cart badge at the top. as well as sending its product ID as a props to `Cart.jsx`.
3. When user visit Cart.jsx page, we will fetching its product details based on products ID[send by props prev. step]

**Please checkout this samall video:[click](https://keerthanblog1234.blogspot.com/2021/08/blog-post.html)**

There is Nothing problem in HomePage and ProductDetails page, only facing in Cart

**Homepage.jsx - Home Page - Displaying all products from API through map()**

```
 <div className="row ">
           {
              items.myItems.map((itm,index)=>( 
                    <div className="col-sm  justify-content-between position-relative d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">
                        <img src={itm.image} id={`thummbnail_id${itm.id}`} alt="" height="300" width="300" className="text-center thumbnail" />
                         
                        <h4>{itm.title}</h4>
                        <p>Rs.{itm.price}</p>
                        <li className="btn  mb-5 btn-primary"><Link className="text-white" to={`/products-details/${itm.id}`}>VIEW DETAILS</Link></li>
                    </div>
              ))   
           }
            </div>
```

**ProductDetails.jsx - Product Details - Displaying particular product details**

```
<div className="row">
             { 
              initData1.products.map((item,index)=>
              {
                if(getId!=item.id)
                {
                  return <div className="col-sm  justify-content-between position-relative d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">
                  <p>{index}</p>
                  <p>{item.id}</p>
                    <img src={item.image} id={`thummbnail_id${item.id}`} alt="" height="300" width="300" className="text-center thumbnail" />
                  <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                  <p>Rs.{item.price}</p>
                  <li className="btn  mb-5 btn-primary"><Link className="text-white" to={`/products-details/${item.id}`}>VIEW DETAILS</Link></li>
                  </div>
                }
              } 
            )}
            </div>
```

**Header.jsx - Header for displaying cart Badge**

```
import {useState,React,useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import '../../src/head_cont.css'
function Header(props) {
    return (
        <div className="head_cont">            
            <div className="container">
                <div className="left">
                     <li className="logo text-light">SHOP69</li>
                </div>
                <div className="right">
                <ul>
                    <li className="header_links mx-4"><Link className="link" to="/">HOME</Link></li>
                    <Link to="/"><i class="fas cart_icon cart_icon_resp pt-4  text-white fa-2x fa-home"></i></Link>
                    {/* <li className="header_links mx-4"><a className="link" href="#container_id">PRODUCTS</a></li> */}
                    <li className="header_links mx-4"><Link className="link" to="/cart-details">VISIT STORE</Link></li>
                    <Link to="/cart-details"><i className=" cart_icon pt-4  fa-2x fas text-light  fa-shopping-bag"></i>{props.text>=1 ? <span className="badge" id="badge">{props.text}</span> : ""}</Link>
                </ul>               
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    )
   
}
export default Header
```

**CartDeails.jsx - Cart Page**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import '../../src/cart-details.css'
function CartDetails(props) {
  const[cart,setCart]=useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    try
    {
      let id=props.id
      fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`).then(function(res){
        return res.json();
      }).then(function(data){

        console.log(data)
        setCart([...cart,data])
      })
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      console.log("Something went wrong while fetching Cart items")
    }
 
  }, [])
  if(props.val>=1)
  {
  return (
    <div>
      {cart.map((item,index)=>(
      <div className="cart_cont text-dark">
            <div className="innerDiv row m-auto  mt-4  d-flex shadow-lg container">
              <div className="d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center flex-column col-sm d-flex id">
                <label htmlFor="id" className="text-danger fw-bold m-auto">ID</label>
                  <p className="m-auto" id="id">{item.id}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex  col-sm  thumbnail">
                <img src={item.image} className="mt-1 mb-1" alt="image" height="100px" width="80px"/>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column col-sm  quantity">
                <label htmlFor="title" className="text-danger fw-bold m-auto">Title</label>
                <p className="m-auto" id="title">{item.title}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex align-items-center col-sm  flex-column unitPrice">
              <label htmlFor="unitprice" className="text-danger fw-bold m-auto">Unit Price</label>
                <p className="m-auto unitprice" id="unitprice">Rs. {item.price}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column col-sm  total">
              <label htmlFor="total" className="text-danger fw-bold m-auto">Total</label>
                <p className="m-auto total" id="total">N/A</p>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex align-items-center  col-sm  rmBtn">
                  <i class="far fa-2x m-auto fa-trash-alt"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
       ))
  }
    </div>
      
  )
}
else
{
  return (
    <div className="no_items">
      <div className="no_items_bg text-center">
          <h2 className="display-5 fw-bold">Cart is Empty</h2>
          <i class="fas fa-5x fa-cat"></i>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
}
export default CartDetails
```

As am familiar with `React Functional Component` and whole code is given here.
Please help me.
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Show conssole.log(cart) in `CartDeails`

Comment: When you revisit your `Cart` page, your state gets initialize again result in an empty array, you will need to store your card array in a global store or in a Database to reserve it.

Comment: I agree with Ryan. It looks like `CartDetails` is remounted and the cart state starts over. [Lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or use global state in a React context or redux (or similar).

Comment: @Viet  `console(cart)` returns an empty array

Comment: @RyanLe, without using any DB, can we store previous cart without get reinitialize

Comment: Sure we can, there are a few options to choose from: Redux, Context API, or like @DrewReese said,  lift state up. Another possible solution could be to store your card in a localStorage.

Comment: @RyanLe okay. is it possible to lift state up in React Functional component?

Comment: Class or Functional Component both have a state, so it's both possible to do so.

Comment: Yes, Lifting state up is a "design pattern", it works regardless of class or function components, where state is lifted to the nearest common ancestor and state & callbacks are passed down as props to children.

Comment: @RyanLe ok. thank you but I have one more question. have you noticed in that video when i clicked on `ADD TO CART` button the page get reloaded. I want to know why and I don't want to reload. please help me

Comment: @RyanLe video link https://keerthanblog1234.blogspot.com/2021/08/blog-post.html

Comment: It's another context to this question, would you mind creating another one with a detailed explanation?

Comment: @DrewReese am beginner to React, can you please share any link or site that can help me easy to learn about this

Comment: It's doesn't look like the page gets refresh anw.

Comment: I included a link to the relevant resource in my comment.

Comment: @RyanLe ok. am not shared code yet, let me raise a new question about that component. Anyway thanks a lot sir ;)

Comment: @DrewReese ok sir, Thanks a lot :)